# Licence Error for Matlab 2012a on Ubuntu 12.04 (64-bit)

Tags: 12.04, matlab

I have installed Matlab 2012a on ubuntu 12.04, while providing the licence I find the following error:

```bash
Could not complete Activation because the License File could not be written to disk.  
You might not have write permission on the License File or the folder.
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/licenses/license_Malhar-PC_161052_R2012a.lic  
  See your System Administrator for assistance. The specific error message text is: 
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/licenses/license_Malhar-PC_161052_R2012a.lic
  (No such file or directory).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I would try creating the directory the license should be written to. Open a terinal with Alt-Ctrl-T and enter:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/licenses
sudo chmod a+rw  /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/licenses
```

The first two of these may already exist, and if so that's OK, just go on. Then try the license install again.

Comment: You only need `sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/licenses` which will create parent folders if they are absent.

Comment: @John tried. It still fails.

Comment: @MalTec Please mark it as unaccepted so that your question still gets attention from the community. What happened when you tried this? (A permission problem perhaps?) If so are you running privileged when you try to activate the license? If not we will need to set corresponding privileges on the directory.

Comment: @Adrian Changed the answer to incorporate your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnSGruber  the answer provided by both of u(@Adrian)  was an essential step towards achieving it. However I had to use chmod from root to allow write permission to normal user. Would be nice if u can incorporate that as well.

Comment: Aha, yes, looks like (at least for the activation run) you'd need to run Matlab with root privileges, or change the permissions or owner on the folder to permit standard users to write to it.

Comment: @Maltec, I've added the chmod command for reading and writing to the question. If you're all set now would be the right time to accept the answer. If there's more too it, however, please add a comment.

Answer (score 0):

gksudo ./activate_matlab.sh

This is a graphical overlay for sudo and will solve the problem.